# simulation using multivariate normal distribution (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, simulation

i am using mvnrnd function in a simulation function i have created

i have the following:

if row of sigma less than or =5 (run of simulaion function i'v created=1000)the function works BUT if the row of the segma matrix more than 5 (and run=1000 of the function i created )it return error message: SIGMA matrix must be positive semi definit matrix.

AND

if i run the simulation 50 times and the row of the sigma matrix =10 (for example)

it works

HOW can i make mvnrnd works in the simulation?

Comment: How do you create the sigma matrix? some code would help

Answer (score 0):

I assume the command is something like:
    R=mvnrnd(mu,SIGMA)

The elements of SIGMA must be the covariances which by definition are positive and hence SIGMA must be a positive semi-definite matrix. i.e. it has positive or equal to zero eigenvalues.

Thus, you are feeding your function with a SIGMA that is ERRONEOUS.

I would suggest that you check your code or post it here.